# Branching of $SU(3)$ under $D_8$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, representation-theory

The question is to work out the branching of $SU(3)$ representations of $\mathbf{3}, \mathbf{\overline{3}}, \mathbf{8}$ under the dihedral group $D_8 = \langle r,s \mid r^4 = s^2 = e, rs=sr^{-1} \rangle$, where we view

$$
r = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
s = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

so that $D_8 \subseteq SU(3)$.

I have worked out all the five irreducible representations, but have no idea what $\mathbf{3}, \mathbf{\overline{3}}, \mathbf{8}$ are so can't work out their restrictions to $D_8$.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to construct the $SU(3)$ irreps you need is probably to use the factorization of $SU(3)$ in a sequence of $SU(2)$ elements.

There are many such factorizations but from the form of your $r$ the useful one is likely as the product
$$
R(\Omega)=R_{23}(\omega_1)R_{12}(\omega_2)R_{23}(\omega_3) \tag{1}
$$
which would allow you to write
$$
r= R_{23}(0,\pi,0)
$$
(or something like this).  The paper

> de Guise, Hubert, Olivia Di Matteo, and Luis L. Sánchez-Soto. "Simple factorization of unitary transformations." Physical Review A 97.2 (2018): 022328.

(arXiv version [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00735)) gives details on this factorization and contains a [github link](https://github.com/glassnotes/Caspar) to a Python code that will find the appropriate angles of the $SU(2)$ subblocks automatically (although it's not hard to figure out the parameters given the simplicity of the elements in your subgroup).

The **3** is just the $3\times 3$ defining representation, while **3$^*$** is its complex conjugate so if you literally get **3$^*$** by taking the complex conjugate of the matrix representation of **3**.  In **3** each $R_{ij}$ transformation of the decomposition of (1) is actually a $2\times 2$ $SU(2)$ block-diagonal matrix - *v.g.* $R_{23}$ is of the form
\begin{align}
R_{23}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
0&A&B\\
0&-B^*&A^*\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
so you get a generic $SU(3)$ element of **3** by simple matrix multiplication of the appropriate blocks.

Since  **3$\otimes$ 3$^*$=8+0** you can probably get away with just tensoring the $D_8$ irreps in **3** and **3$^*$** and making sure you stay away **0** (which is the trivial $SU(3)$ and so can only contain the identity of $D_8$ once) to get the contents of $D_8$ in **8**.  Alternatively you can construct explicitly the **8** using for instance ref[43] of the above paper, but that's a lot more work.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is nice to see an explicit calculation. For a simple-minded person like me it's always nice to see how the algebra works out.

Let's start with the character table of $D_8$ (actually some people call it $D_4$ but it doesn't matter).

$\begin{array}{c| c c }
 & 1 & 1' & 1'' & 1''' & 2 \\
\hline
{e} & 1  & 1 & 1  &1  & 2\\
{r, rs} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0\\
{s,sr^2} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
{r^2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
{sr,sr^3} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}$

If you calculate the matrix products as written in the first column of the table for your given matrices and take the traces you get the characters for the $\bf 3$ in the second column. The last coulmn is obtained from the generators $r$ and $s$ in the adjoint represenation $\bf 8$ (cf. the end of this post).

$\begin{array}{c| c c }
 & 3 & 8  \\
\hline
{e} & 3  & 8 \\
{r, rs} & 1 & 0\\
{s,sr^2} & -1 & 0 \\
{r^2} & -1 & 0 \\
{sr,sr^3} & -1 & 0  \\
\end{array}$

From this, you can read off the following branching rules:
$$ \bf 3\rightarrow 2+1'$$
and 
$$\bf 8\rightarrow 2+2+1+1'+1''+1'''$$

PS: Your generators $r$ and $s$ would have the following matrix representation with the choices you made for your fundamental represenation:
$$r=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and 
$$s = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: unless you describe how to get your $8\times 8$ rep of $r$ and $s$ this might as well be black magic.

Comment: It's a standard procedure: Calculate the structure constants. Use them as adjoint representation. Exponentiate and using the same coordinates, that were used for the example in the fundamental representation. It's easily performed with CAS, no black magic needed.